# How do I resolve this error while storing the data in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to store the data in the Hadoop and I am working with windows system. After creating the directory, I would like to store the data in that. But, I can't able to store my data in Hadoop. It throws the following error;

```java
WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /sample/numbers.txt._COPYING_ could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 0 datanode(s) running and 0 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2702)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:875)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:991)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:872)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:818)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2678)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1511)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1367)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:228)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:510)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1081)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1668)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:716)
copyFromLocal: File /sample/numbers.txt._COPYING_ could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 0 datanode(s) running and 0 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

Answer (score 2):

> There are 0 datanode(s) running...

You need to start the datanode and resubmit the job

And if you already did, then look at the datanode process logs to see why it crashed